# Calculating the coupling capacitor

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, capacitance

Up to now i have been able to determine the values of resistors. But i can't seem to understand how to find the value of the **capacitor (Cb)**.
[image]

Question: Calculate **Cb** to let pass frequency starting from 100 Hz. How do i find the impedance of the capacitor Cb, so i can find the actual value of capacitor to be used in this case.

We have,

1. R1 = 390 KOhm
2. R2 = 82 KOhm
3. Rc = 5.5 KOhm
4. Re = 1 KOhm

E12 series is used to determine the value of the resistors.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the input impedance of the bias network?

Comment: Ohh!! I just realized i have an entire topic to cover before i can ask the questions after i saw the input impedance of the bias network! Its just been a week we started our new semiter and we already have lab next week. So i had to learn quickly. Thank you @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams